# Jaws does not read the equation just after the html-table in ie browser

Tags: html-table, mathjax, mathml, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using windows 8 - IE11 with jaws 2018. I have added a html-table and just after that table I have added a math equation(rendered using Mathjax). When I press tab key, focus goes into the table and using keyboard shortcuts I navigate throughout the table. Again when I press tab key, focus does not go to the math equation written after the table.
[Math equation in table and after the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynCJZ.png)
[image: Math equation in table and after the table]

```
<div class="al-diag-test-question-content-wrapper">
       <div class="al-diag-test-question-label" tabindex="0" aria-label="Question Number Q 30.37">Q 30.37:</div>
       <div class="al-diag-test-question-raw-content" id="qcdata">
          <div style="visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 1px; width: auto; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; line-height: normal; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: normal;">
         <div id="MathJax_Hidden"></div>
          </div>
          <inline class="para-content-wrap">
         <label tabindex="0">  Given  </label>
         <label tabindex="0" class="math-label">
            <span id="swformula-4c512d5f-ebb3-46e3-936f-0fd95ba2d82a" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
               <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
               <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-5-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                  <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-30" style="width: 2.153em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.723em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1001.67em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-31"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-32"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-33" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-34" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-35" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-36" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-37" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
                  <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                     <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                           <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                           <mi>f</mi>
                           <mo>(</mo>
                           <mi>x</mi>
                           <mo>)</mo>
                        </mrow>
                     </math>
                  </span>
               </span>
               <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-5"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></math></script>
            </span>
         </label>
         <label tabindex="0">  and  </label>
         <label tabindex="0" class="math-label">
            <span id="swformula-0fa8a996-e05a-4eac-81b6-ed19f8607e65" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
               <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
               <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-6-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                  <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-38" style="width: 2.207em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.777em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1001.72em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-39"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-40"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-41" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-42" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">g</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-43" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-44" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-45" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
                  <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                     <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                        <mrow>
                           <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                           <mi>g</mi>
                           <mo>(</mo>
                           <mi>x</mi>
                           <mo>)</mo>
                        </mrow>
                     </math>
                  </span>
               </span>
               <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-6"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo></mrow></math></script>
            </span>
         </label>
         <label tabindex="0">  , select whether the given statements are true or false.&nbsp;</label>
          </inline>
          <div align="center">
         <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" tabindex="0">
            <!--#text-->
            <tbody>
               <!--#text-->
               <tr>
                  <!--#text-->
                  <td align="right" style=";border:none;">
                     <span id="swformula-e7d98024-95a9-4bd4-9158-eff0ca8ada4a" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
                        <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
                        <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-7-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                           <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-46" style="width: 3.444em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 2.745em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1002.69em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-47"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-48"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-49" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-50" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-51" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-52" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-53" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-54" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; padding-left: 0.325em;">=</span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
                           <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                              <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                                 <mrow>
                                    <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                                    <mi>f</mi>
                                    <mo>(</mo>
                                    <mi>x</mi>
                                    <mo>)</mo>
                                    <mo>=</mo>
                                 </mrow>
                              </math>
                           </span>
                        </span>
                        <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-7"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo></mrow></math></script>
                     </span>
                  </td>
                  <!--#text-->
                  <td align="left" style=";border:none;">
                     <span id="swformula-ad7f29e8-c212-4e49-ab91-b88790e0f81f" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
                        <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
                        <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-8-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mstyle mathsize=&quot;24px&quot;><mfrac><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>-</mo><mo>5</mo></mrow><mo>6</mo></mfrac></mstyle></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                           <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-55" style="width: 2.476em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.992em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(-0.374em, 1001.99em, 1.669em, -999.997em); top: -1.019em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-56"><span class="mstyle" id="MathJax-Span-57"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-58"><span class="mfrac" id="MathJax-Span-59"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.669em; height: 0px; margin-right: 0.164em; margin-left: 0.164em;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.175em, 1001.45em, 4.25em, -999.997em); top: -4.621em; left: 50%; margin-left: -0.75em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-60"><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-61" style="font-size: 91.2%; font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-62" style="font-size: 91.2%; font-family: STIXGeneral;">−</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-63" style="font-size: 91.2%; font-family: STIXGeneral;">5</span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.981em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.175em, 1000.43em, 4.142em, -999.997em); top: -3.492em; left: 50%; margin-left: -0.212em;"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-64" style="font-size: 91.2%; font-family: STIXGeneral;">6</span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 3.981em;"></span></span><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0.863em, 1001.67em, 1.239em, -999.997em); top: -1.341em; left: 0em;"><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: 0em; border-top: 1.4px solid; width: 1.669em; height: 0px;"></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 1.078em;"></span></span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 1.024em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.663em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 2.337em;"></span></span></nobr>
                           <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                              <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                                 <mstyle mathsize="24px">
                                    <mfrac>
                                       <mrow>
                                          <mi>x</mi>
                                          <mo>-</mo>
                                          <mo>5</mo>
                                       </mrow>
                                       <mo>6</mo>
                                    </mfrac>
                                 </mstyle>
                              </math>
                           </span>
                        </span>
                        <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-8"><math ext:algorithm="1" xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mstyle mathsize="24px"><mfrac><mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>-</mo><mo>5</mo></mrow><mo>6</mo></mfrac></mstyle></math></script>
                     </span>
                  </td>
                  <!--#text-->
               </tr>
               <!--#text-->
               <tr>
                  <!--#text-->
                  <td align="right" style=";border:none;">
                     <span id="swformula-c3935677-23a9-4ad5-8946-5a8fbcb78e59" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
                        <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
                        <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-9-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                           <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-65" style="width: 3.497em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 2.798em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1002.75em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-66"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-67"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-68" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-69" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">g</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-70" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-71" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-72" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-73" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; padding-left: 0.325em;">=</span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
                           <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                              <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                                 <mrow>
                                    <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                                    <mi>g</mi>
                                    <mo>(</mo>
                                    <mi>x</mi>
                                    <mo>)</mo>
                                    <mo>=</mo>
                                 </mrow>
                              </math>
                           </span>
                        </span>
                        <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-9"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo></mrow></math></script>
                     </span>
                  </td>
                  <!--#text-->
                  <td align="left" style=";border:none;">
                     <span id="swformula-bae95aed-62c8-4d67-a063-b5900673a11c" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
                        <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
                        <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-10-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mo>6</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mo>5</mo></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
                           <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-74" style="width: 3.497em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 2.798em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1002.75em, 2.745em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-75"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-76"><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-77" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">6</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-78" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.325em;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-79" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">+</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-80" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; padding-left: 0.325em;">5</span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.13em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.07em;"></span></span></nobr>
                           <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                              <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                                 <mrow>
                                    <mo>6</mo>
                                    <mi>x</mi>
                                    <mo>+</mo>
                                    <mo>5</mo>
                                 </mrow>
                              </math>
                           </span>
                        </span>
                        <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-10"><math ext:algorithm="1" xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mo>6</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mo>5</mo></mrow></math></script>
                     </span>
                  </td>
                  <!--#text-->
               </tr>
               <!--#text-->
            </tbody>
            <!--#text-->
         </table>
          </div>
          <br>
          <label tabindex="0" class="math-label">
         <span id="swformula-985ced54-ecc4-47f5-bc16-89abbf04dc41" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
            <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-11-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
               <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-81" style="width: 5.809em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.68em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1004.68em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-82"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-83"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-84" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-85" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-86" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-87" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">g</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-88" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-89" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-90" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-91" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-92" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; padding-left: 0.325em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-93" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.325em;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
               <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                     <mrow>
                        <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                        <mi>f</mi>
                        <mo>(</mo>
                        <mi>g</mi>
                        <mo>(</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                        <mo>)</mo>
                        <mo>)</mo>
                        <mo>=</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                     </mrow>
                  </math>
               </span>
            </span>
            <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-11"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow></math></script>
         </span>
          </label>
          <label tabindex="0">  is  </label>
          <span style="padding: 2px; -moz-user-select: none;">
         <span style="padding: 0px;" class="select-box-tag-wrapper question-element-wrapper">
            <select id="1" class="question-raw-content-dropdown custom-select-box" style="width:80px;" aria-label="  Given  and  , select whether the given statements are true or false.                                 is  .   is  .    select dropdown values">
               <option></option>
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
         </span>
          </span>
          <label tabindex="0"> .</label><br>
          <label tabindex="0" class="math-label">
         <span id="swformula-300f099b-f7ec-4313-9382-9ce837ee5d6c" class="swformula" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit; display: none;"></span>
            <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-12-Frame" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mrow><mtext>&amp;#x2009;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow></math>" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
               <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-94" style="width: 5.809em; display: inline-block;"><span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 4.68em; height: 0px; font-size: 124%;"><span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(1.669em, 1004.68em, 2.906em, -999.997em); top: -2.524em; left: 0em;"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-95"><span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-96"><span class="mtext" id="MathJax-Span-97" style="font-family: STIXGeneral;"><span style="margin-left: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-98" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">g</span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-99" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-100" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">f<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.164em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-101" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">(</span></span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-102" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-103" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-104" style="vertical-align: 0em;"><span style="font-family: STIXGeneral;">)</span></span><span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-105" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; padding-left: 0.325em;">=</span><span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-106" style="font-family: STIXGeneral; font-style: italic; padding-left: 0.325em;">x<span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; height: 1px; width: 0.003em;"></span></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.53em;"></span></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: -0.33em; border-left: 0px solid; width: 0px; height: 1.203em;"></span></span></nobr>
               <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation">
                  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                     <mrow>
                        <mtext>&thinsp;</mtext>
                        <mi>g</mi>
                        <mo>(</mo>
                        <mi>f</mi>
                        <mo>(</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                        <mo>)</mo>
                        <mo>)</mo>
                        <mo>=</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                     </mrow>
                  </math>
               </span>
            </span>
            <script type="math/mml" id="MathJax-Element-12"><math xmlns:ext="http://www.wiley.com/namespaces/wiley/qti/ext" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mtext>&thinsp;</mtext><mi>g</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>f</mi><mo>(</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>)</mo><mo>)</mo><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow></math></script>
         </span>
          </label>
          <label tabindex="0">  is  </label>
          <span style="padding: 2px; -moz-user-select: none;">
         <span style="padding: 0px;" class="select-box-tag-wrapper question-element-wrapper">
            <select id="2" class="question-raw-content-dropdown custom-select-box" style="width:80px;" aria-label="  Given  and  , select whether the given statements are true or false.                                 is  .   is  .    select dropdown values">
               <option></option>
               <option value="true">true</option>
               <option value="false">false</option>
            </select>
         </span>
          </span>
          <label tabindex="0"> .&nbsp;</label>
          <div style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px;">
         <div id="MathJax_Font_Test" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: auto; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; line-height: normal; letter-spacing: normal; word-spacing: normal; font-size: 40px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: STIXSizeOneSym, sans-serif;"></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try adding a live code sample that allows others to reproduce the issue. Without more information on the actual page, there's not much one can say.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I added the code in the question.